# Uncaught Error : Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular8, formgroups

I am newbie in angular, tried all possible ways suggested by stack overflow but no success till now. 
FormGroup is not binding. I have already added ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts and *.component.ts. I have been using Angular 8.x

Details:

```
            Package                           Version
            -----------------------------------------------------------
            @angular/animations               8.2.7
            @angular/cdk                      8.2.0
            @angular/cli                      8.3.4
            @angular/forms                    8.2.7
            @angular/http                     7.2.15
            @angular/material                 8.2.0
            @angular/router                   8.2.7
            @ngtools/webpack                  8.3.4
            @schematics/angular               8.3.4
            @schematics/update                0.803.4
            rxjs                              6.4.0
            typescript                        3.5.3
            webpack                           4.39.2
```

======================

## Component html File

```
<div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="profile">
                  <form [FormGroup]="catCreate" class="example-form">
```

=======================================

## create-category.component.ts

```
       import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
       import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

            @Component({
              templateUrl: './create-category.component.html', ...
            })

            export class CreateCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
              catCreate: FormGroup; ...
```

================================

## app.module.ts

```
            import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
            import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
            import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
            import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
            import { CreateCategoryComponent } from './components/create-category/create-category.component';
            import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
            import { MaterialsModule } from './material-module';

            @NgModule({
              declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                UploaderComponent,
                CreateCategoryComponent
              ],
              imports: [
                MaterialsModule,
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                .......
```

```
    Error: Compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
        Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("a">
       <form [ERROR ->][FormGroup]="catCreate" class="example-form">
                                 ng:///AppModule/CreateCategoryComponent.html@8:30
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind it with lower camel case: [formGroup] instead of [FormGroup].